# turning off notification in chrome webdriver using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

[image]

Hello all and thanks in advance for your help

trying to make a Facebook script, and notifications like the picture always appear. I used the following code to turn it off but does not work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2})


s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)


driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/login/')

time.sleep(1)

driver.maximize_window()
```

if chrome does not show this notification, it would go for the next command unless I do it manually every time.

how can I fix this, please?

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

1. You didn't import `Options` from selenium. Make sure to add the following line to your imports:

   ```
   from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
   ```
2. It looks like you didn't pass the options variable to the function `driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)`. It should be this:

   ```
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chrome_options)
   ```

One last thing to help you out. There's an argument you can pass to start the window maximized so you don't have to call `driver.maximize_window()`. Add this to to the options:

```
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
```

The full code you can copy:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
# Notice I didn't use a "--" in front of "start-maximized"
# I just know this works, maybe having "--" in front doesn't matter, I don't know
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2})


s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chrome_options)


driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/login/')
```